# can a Java annotation insert a breakpoint in the code

Tags: java, annotations, breakpoints

I'm looking at annotations to insert and activate or deactivate breakpoint in the code with the help of an annotation processor. 
I'm not sure if the processoer can do that.
So the question is:

Can an annotation insert a breakpoint in the code?

Million thanks
Adrians

Comment: I'm not an expert on how breakpoints, or annotations work, but if you are using an IDE such as eclipse, I'd think as long as you have the source code for the annotation, you should be able to set a break point on that code, and as long as it is linked to the project as source, it should catch, and you should be able to step through it.

On that note, I'm not exactly sure how annotations work.  I think they can modify the bytecode, so it is possible that it would not work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _inserting a breakpoint_ - which debugger should stop on it, and why wouldn't just setting such breakpoint in a debugger be enough?

Comment: I'm curious what your use case would be. Do you want to ship breakpoints with your app? Otherwise this doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: In addition to what's said above; there's no support for annotating random lines of code; see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html for valid targets. Also, annotation processors only run during the compilation phase.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is possible, the question is only the cost :D

First an annotation cannot be put on a random location. Big limitation for you...

Second and the most important, a breakpoint is not part of the code. Basically when you set a breakpoint in your IDE, it sends a command to your program that say "hey I want to stop there". On the program side, there is an agent responsible of listening this kind of command and which implement a specific protocol: [jdwp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdwp-spec.html). On the client side the jdk provides you a tools to talk to this agent : [jdb](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html).

So the only solution would be to have a tool that parses your code to find annotation and launch some breakpoint instructions. In order to stop at a specific line, you will to specify the line number in your annotations...

Conclusion: very complicate to implement, very limited and... why doing that???